# NuGet init.ps1 executing twice

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am following the solution found at "[Create a NuGet package that shows update notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050030/create-a-nuget-package-that-shows-update-notifications)" to get a notification of a nuget package update.

However the init.ps1 script is executing twice.

I stripped all the code out so that only the following is in init.ps1.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
if ($project -eq $null) {
$project = Get-Project
}

Write-Host "Hello, I'm running inside of init.ps1"
```

When I close the solution and reopen it, in the output window the text is there twice.

[image: duplicate init execution]

I am using VS 2012, NuGet 2.2.31210

I checked the packages.config file and there is only one entry for my package.

Why is it running twice and is there any way to get it to only run once?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: You have a typo in your third line `$projet = Get-Project` should be `$project = Get-Project`

Comment: Next day and after a reboot of Windows I cannot get the problem to duplicate again. Sigh. Seems like I forgot the cardinal rule, if something odd is happening and it does not work, first reboot.

Comment: You're not crazy. I just ran into the same problem, over and over... until I restarted VS, and couldn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In init.ps1 script, Get-Project will return a random project in the solution but not the particular project the package has been installed.

Use $projects = Get-Project -All to get the list of projects in solution, loop through the projects and search the packages.config to check if the current project has the package installed.