# How to get notification when nuget package update available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, notifications, nuget, nuget-package

Is there any way in Visual Studio that I can register to get notification every time new version of installed nuget package available, without open the nuget packege manager UI?
(like we get notification for VS updates)

Answer (score 6):

As an idea, if you have an RSS reader (like Feedly), you can subscribe to the releases feed

(for example, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/atom.xml)

Answer (score 4):

You can consume the RSS release feed from Nuget with IFTTT's Rss to Email applet. When new entries show up; IFTTT sends you an email.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to receive e-mail notifications only for major releases but not for minor releases etc.? as far as i've seen, there's no dedicated rss feed that contains only major releases.

Answer (score 2):

The NuGet plugin doesn't support this to my knowledge and doesn't appear to be planning on it.

[The best reference I have for this a couple years old.](http://blog.nuget.org/20141008/vs-tooling.html)

[Some others have attempted to find a work-around.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050030/create-a-nuget-package-that-shows-update-notifications)

Answer (score 2):

At present version of Visual Studio, I don’t find any settings can add the NuGet Package updates notification into Visual Studio Notification window. Since NuGet Package Manager is an extension for Visual Studio, I have submit a feature request for this extension in below link. You can add your own idea for that feedback.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3292